# please check my verification using email and password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

now im trying to check in my category controller if user logged in let him post category otherwise show him "You must be logged in to create a category" but the category is posted wether user is logged in or not logged in it caused me frustration for 4 hours still beginner

this where the problem it bypass

```
routeCategory.post("/category", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body || !req.body.category_id) {
    return res.status(400).send("category missing");
  }

  const id = req.body.category_id;
  const one = category.categoryData.find(
    (Element) => Element.category_id === id
  );
  const email2 = req.params.email;
  const found = User.data.find((email) => email.email === email2);
  if (User.login(email2, req.body.password) == false) {
    return res.status(401).send("You are not authorized");
  } else if (one) {
    return res.status(409).send("Category already exists");
  } else {
    const newCategory = {
      category_id: req.body.category_id,
      categoryName: req.body.categoryName,
    };

    category.createCategory(newCategory);
    return res.sendStatus(201);
  }
});
```

```
  static login = function (email, password) {
    // checking if the email and password are in the data array
    // then the email and password must be the same as the user entered it
    // return email if it's right

    // const found = User.data.find(
    //   (element) => element.email === email && element.password === password
    // );

    const found = User.data.find((element) => {
      return element.email === email && element.password === password;
    });
    console.log(User.data);
    console.log(email, password);
    if (found) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I think you should try to use for login JWT token and check if user is logged by token not by user email and pass. https://jwt.io/introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controlling access like this should be done via a separate middleware:

```
const checkAccess = (req, res, next) => {
  // fetch user and check requirements
  if (/* user can access route*/) {
    next()
  } else {
    next(new Error("No access"))
  }
}

routeCategory.post("/category", checkAccess, (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body || !req.body.category_id) {
  ....
```

Also you should be storing the password in a way that checking it with `===` isn't possible, use [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) or [argon2](https://www.veracode.com/blog/secure-development/zero-hashing-under-10-minutes-argon2-nodejs) for password hashing.